# UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '59.jpg

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr 
!pip install pytesseract

from google.colab import files
file_uploaded = files.upload()

import pytesseract 
import cv2 
import os 
from PIL import Image 
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from google.colab import drive
from google.colab import files

image=cv2.imread('prac.jpg') 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

filename = "{}.jpg".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), lang = None)
os.remove(filename)

print(text)
cv2_imshow(image)
```

In the line "text = ~~", this code cause error "UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '59.jpg'". But I don't even have image named 59. what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. But you are supposed to restart Colab runtime once *pytesseract* and its dependencies are installed, as you were guided by pip install (in red):
**You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.** ,
followed by <kbd>RESTART RUNTIME</kbd> button.

After restarting runtime and running that cell again you should get expected result. Though you'd probably want to re-organize your Notebook a bit and split that code (at least) into 3 different cells:

- installing dependencies
- importing modules
- your image upload & OCR code

---

*"image named 59"* is created by `image=cv2.imread('prac.jpg'); gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! restarting runtime solved this problem!